# Variables in urllib, from python request?

Tags: python, urllib

I'm currently trying to get images that are retrieved via URL to download locally. I cannot find solid documentation on how to utilize variables instead of one image at a time like below.
This is the below data class for image that cards utilizes. To call the image for the variable.

```
@dataclass
class CardImage():
    small: str
    large: str


import urllib.request

Cards = Card.all()

for card in Cards:

    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://images.pokemontcg.io/sm75/1_hires.png", "sm75-1.jpg")
```

It also keeps throwing a urlretrieve

```
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:,  

urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
```

Comment: I have been staring at this post for 5 minutes, and I still have no idea of what's your question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution that worked for downloading images from a URL, saving to a specific file, reporting if an error occurred, and allowing to bypass HTTP error.

```
from email.mime import image
from pokemontcgsdk import Card
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import os


def downloadImage(url, filename):
  headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }

  request = Request(url, None, headers)
  data = urlopen(request).read()

  with open(filename,'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 images_directory = 'All Pokemon'
 os.makedirs(images_directory, exist_ok=True)

 cards = Card.all()
 for card in cards:
   print("Downloading " + card.name + " " + card.images.small)
   url = card.images.small
   filename = os.path.join(images_directory, card.id + ".png")
     try:
       downloadImage(url, filename)
     except HTTPError:
        print("  There is no image for: " + card.name + " " + card.images.small)
```